# What is your way to add images into panels - simple and fast?

Tags: media, panels, files

How can you upload images into panels simply and fast? That's all I need - images in panels, simple and fast. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) with [CKFinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder):

1. On pane gear menu click add content
2. Choose 'New custom content'
3. In the body field use the image button to either find an existing image on the server or upload a new one.

CKFinder requires a licence, it's pretty cheap.

Comment: I'm looking for something free, have any other suggestion (except Media that is buggy in Panels or IMCE which is kinda tiring in it's current architecture) ?

Comment: Sorry, this is the simplest, fastest option I know.  Others may have suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) + [Asset](https://www.drupal.org/project/asset)